# totally bounded infinite metric space <=> metric close to zero!

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space. Prove that M is totally bounded if, and only if, for every infinite set $A\subseteq M$ and $\epsilon>0$ there exist $x,y\in A$ such that $d(x,y)<\epsilon.$
Of course, $x\neq y$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? Where are you getting stuck? Have you been able to prove either direction? Do you understand the definition of "totally bounded"?

Comment: I know that the "=>" direction is quite obvious. That is, by the definition, for $\epsilon>0$ we have that $M=\cup_k B(x_k,\epsilon)$  $(1)$ for a finite set $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$. So we can find $x,y\in A$ with $d(x,y)<\epsilon$ or else  (1) would be violated. It's the "<=" that seems hard.

Comment: Great.  For this and for future questions, that's the kind of "context" you should include along with your question statement

Answer (score 3):

Here is my try. We wil prove the "<=" direction via it's contrapositive, so we will suppose that $(M,d)$ is a metric space which is not totally bounded and obtain an infinite subset $A \subset M$ such that $d(x,y) \geq \varepsilon$ for every $x,y \in A$ and for some $\varepsilon > 0$.

Since $M$ is not totally bounded, there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ such that no finite collection $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\} \subset M$ satisfies $M \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n B(x_i,\varepsilon)$. Pick any point $x_0 \in M$, there exists a point $x_1 \in M$ which does not belong to the ball $B(x_0,\varepsilon)$. Similarly, there exists a point $x_2 \in M$ such that $x_2 \not\in B(x_0,\varepsilon)\cup B(x_1,\varepsilon)$.

So we define a sequence of points inductively, taking $x_0$ as mentioned above, and then, having chosen $x_0,\dots,x_n$, we take a point $x_{n+1} \not\in B(x_0,\varepsilon) \cup \dotsm \cup B(x_n,\varepsilon)$. This gives us an infinite subset $A = \{x_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. This subset is the one we are looking for, because if you take $x_i,x_j \in A$, we may assume that $j>i$ without loss of generality, then by the definition of the sequence, we have that $x_j \not\in B(x_i,\varepsilon)$; so $d(x_i,x_j) \geq \varepsilon$. In resume, for this infinite subset $A$ and for this specific $\varepsilon$, we have $d(x,y) \geq \varepsilon$ for any distinct $x,y \in A$.

Comment: Not bad at all. Nicely done! Upvoted.